# create a custom form inside a block in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-fapi, drupal-forms

I know how to use a module to create a block and I know how to create a custom form using form api.

now, i want to add this custom form inside the block I create.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the following code ([hook_block_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7)):

```
 function yourmodule_block_view($delta='') {
     $block = array();
     switch($delta) {
        case 'block_name':
          $block['subject'] = t("Block Title"); 
          $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('your_form_id');
          break;
     }
     return $block;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create a webform while adding components see the form settings in the upper right:

1. Click on form settings
2. Go to advance settings in bottom and click
3. You find it available as a box checkbox enable that

If enabled this webform will be available as a block.